# Set locale on the fly in laravel4

Tags: php, localization, laravel, laravel-4

After searching through the documentation from laravel 4 I see that the way to set a language is to do

```
App::setLocale('en');
```

But how do I use this in combination with for example a language switcher on my website that a visitor can click on to change the language on the fly? and to remember this with a cookie or something?

It seems that in laravel 3 it was much easier but since im new to laravel I don't know how to figure this out so if someone knows what to do and can help me out it would be great :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a way:

Create a route for your language selector:

```
Route::get('language/{lang}', 
           array(
                  'as' => 'language.select', 
                  'uses' => 'LanguageController@select'
                 )
          );
```

Create your language selectors links in Laravel Blade's view:

```
<html><body>

    Please select a Language:

    {{link_to_route('language.select', 'English', array('en'))}}

    {{link_to_route('language.select', 'Portuguese', array('pt'))}}

</body></html>
```

A Controller:

```
Class LanguageController extends BaseController {

    public function select($lang)
    {
        Session::put('lang', $lang);

        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

}
```

Then in your app/start/global.php you can:

```
App::setLocale(Session::get('lang', 'en'));
```

Comment: I don't really get the language selectors? How do I use this where do I place this?

Comment: A thanks that one is clear :) but now I get a Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/" as such route does not exist.

Comment: This is about another route. You need to make sure the route exists. Paste your routes code and your view so we can help you more.

Comment: I have set everything as u gave me in ur example. the only thing I changed was the Redirect::route('home'); to / but both didn't work.

Comment: / is not a route name 'home' might be, if you want to change that you need to use `Route::to('/')`. As I said, not related to my code, but changes you made. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42152/discussion-between-reshad-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro)

Comment: Sorry, it's Redirect::to('/');

Answer (score 4):

There is great library for Laravel that allows you to handle locales flexible - [mcamara laravel localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization). In readme of the project you can find example how to implement such a switcher.