# Changing locale doesn't work on the index page

Tags: php, localization, laravel-4

Somehow I can't change the language of my website in Laravel04 when I am on the index page.

I used this technique

[Set locale on the fly in laravel4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273956/set-locale-on-the-fly-in-laravel4)

To achieve building a multi language website but when I change the language on the index page ( home page ) of the website it doesn't change. the session gives me the correct language back when asking with

```
<?php echo Session::get('lang') ?>
```

Unfortunately the language stays at the main language.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by changing the route for the / in

```
Route::get('/', 'controller@method');
```